# Skip rows copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the issue with skiping the rows from the data source (excel) in adf copy activity.
My dataset looks like on below image. Im trying to skip the first row and make second row as header.

In addition to this I also add the additional column, which should start from I2 cell and not from I1 cell.

but unfortunetly I cant achieve what I want.

Any help is appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same way at my end using the Excel as the Source. and Excel sheet having the Multiple sheets.
[image]
I want to exclude the above Item ID which is A1
And I want to start the first row as header From A4.
So my ADF Source data set configuration is like below.
[image]
And I am writing the Sink to ADLS Gen 2 As a .CSV format.
[image]
Output:
[image]